# Matcher can't match

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code. I need to check the text for existing any of the words from some list of banned words. But even if this word exists in the text matcher doesn't see it. here is the code:

```
final ArrayList<String> regexps = config.getProperty(property);
   for (String regexp: regexps){
   Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(" + regexp + ")", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
   Matcher mt = pt.matcher(plainText);                        
   if (mt.find()){
      result = result + "message can't be processed because it doesn't satisfy the rule " + property;
      reason = false;
      System.out.println("reason" + mt.group() + regexp);
                        }
                    }
```

What is wrong? This code can'f find regexp `в[ыy][шs]лит[еe]`, which is `regexp` in the `plainText = "Вышлите пожалуйста новый счет на оплату на Санг, пока согласовывали, уже
прошли его сроки. Лиценз..."`. I also tried another variants of the `regexp` but everything is useless

Comment: What the parentheses are doing in "(" + keyword + ")" ?

Comment: Why don't you use `plainText.contains(keyword)` for this task?

Comment: Could you provide the values of the `keywords` set and the `plainText` string?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov It should be `".*" + keyword + ".*"` and anyway, it won't work for multilines input texts.

Comment: Nikita, I need to check not only for words but for regexps too, and, by the way it doesn't work even with simple words

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is elsewhere.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(qwer)");
        Matcher mt = pt.matcher("asdf qwer zxcv");
        System.out.println(mt.find());
    }
}
```

This prints out true. You may want to use word boundary as delimiter, though:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\bqwer\\b");
        Matcher mt = pt.matcher("asdf qwer zxcv");
        System.out.println(mt.find());
        mt = pt.matcher("asdfqwer zxcv");
        System.out.println(mt.find());
    }
}
```

The parenthesis are useless unless you need to capture the keyword in a group. But you already have it to begin with.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to say. I changed this:Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(qwer)"); to this: Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\bqwer\\b"); but still have the same result. it can't found any word in the text

Comment: I can't understand how could it change the result. Why after this it began looking for words right?

Comment: @NikitinMikhail It wouldn't change the result. It would help us diagnose the problem. I suspect there is an issue with either plainText or keyword. Also try to print out keyword, by the way :)

Comment: you didn't understand. I understand that that was offered to diagnose the problem. I was kidding about this because the method baegan working right. The only thing I've done is that I changed one string this way: Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(" + keyword + ")", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Comment: I tried to follow your advice and received the following exception' ^ java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: \k is not followed by '<' for named capturing group near index 2
\khkj\b
  ^'

Comment: The regex pattern contains `\\b` at both ends, no `\\k`. `\\b` means "word Boundary".

Comment: yes, I've didn't notice that. but nevertheless it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList's built in functions `indexOf(Object o)` and `contains(Object o)` to check if a String exists anywhere in the Array and where.
e.g.

```
ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
keywords.add("hello");
System.out.println(keywords.contains("hello"));
System.out.println(keywords.indexOf("hello"));
```

outputs: 
true
0

Comment: And how do go through each word of the input text? What about case sensitivity?

Comment: If by input text you mean your blacklisted words, go through the them just just like you are currently, then use `keywords.contains(keyword)`, and I don't think case sensitivity is a problem - make sure your keywords are the right case or make everything `toLower()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to filter out messages which contain banned words using the following regex which uses `OR` operator.

```
private static void findBannedWords() {
    final ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
    keywords.add("f$%k");
    keywords.add("s!@t");
    keywords.add("a$s");

    String input = "what the f$%k";

    String bannedRegex = "";
    for (String keyword: keywords){
        bannedRegex =  bannedRegex + ".*" + keyword + ".*" + "|";
    }

    Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(bannedRegex.substring(0, bannedRegex.length()-1));
    Matcher mt = pt.matcher(input);
    if (mt.matches()) {
         System.out.println("message can't be processed because it doesn't satisfy the rule ");
    }
}
```